# SQL query to get all unique rows with uid

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I want to see which user has received the most highfives using a SQL query. My table looks like following, `id | uid | ip`. Now, I want to count the amount of rows a `uid` has, but it has to be unique with the `ip`. So nobody can give multiple highfives to a person.

I searched around online, and I couldn't find anything about this. If anyone could help me with this, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 3):

you can try like below

```
select ip, count(distinct uid) from table t
group by ip
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT uid,COUNT(ip)NoOfVotes FROM
(SELECT uid,ip,Serial=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ip,uid ORDER BY uid)  FROM 
dbo.tbl_user)A
WHERE Serial=1
GROUP BY uid
```

I think this will give you perfect vote counting. Using Row Number actively remove duplicates from same ip,same uid. Voting to multiple uid from same ip is allowed in this query.